# Commit/Push from Pycharm to GitHub contains packages

Tags: python, github, pycharm

I'm working on a Python app using the Pycharm IDE.  I've just finished the first version of my app and am planning to commit and push to an empty repository on GitHub.

During set up to avoid the constant popup questions about adding files to Git, I choose an option to add all files.  This may have been a mistake as it seems I've added 21,750 files to the repository.  I was expected less than 10.

Looking at the list of tiles I'm seeing nearly all of them are located in the

```
\Lib\site-packages\...
```

with the ... being the various packages that I've imported for the scripts to run.

Should I be excluding everything from this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should remove the libraries from version control.

I suggest using a [gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to ignore the venv folder, .idea, etc.